# What is the formula for calculating reverse CAGR in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How should we calculate CAGR growth for every year in **Ms-Excel**  when we have the ***Starting figure*** and the **CAGR rate for the entire period**?

[image: CAGR Calculation]

So in the image (link above) I have the Starting Value and the CAGR percentage (highlighted in yellow) for each of the country. I need to calculate the Future Value for every year (area highlighted in green).

For example, the global value of smartphones in 2018 is $55 billion. During the period 2018-2027 the CAGR is 6%. So how can I calculate the value for 2019, 2020, 2021, all the way up to 2027?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the Global value for 2019 is in cell C3 and the CAGR column is column L, enter the following formula in cell C3 and then copy the formula to the rest of the range.

```
=B3*(1+$L3/100)
```

The formula works by converting the value in column L (the CAGR) to a percentage and adding that percentage to the cell immediately to the left of the cell with the formula.